# Creating a ViewModel from two classes(models) gives 'No Key Defined' error'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning C# and having trouble with viewmodels and AutoMapper.

I currently have two model classes and one viewmodel as below:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CarShowroom.Models
{
    public class CarModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        public string Manufactuer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int ModelYear { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer manufacturer { get; set; }
        public static int ManufacturerID { get; internal set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarShowroom.Models
{
    public class Manufacturer
    {
        [Key]
        public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
        public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CarModel> carModels { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarShowroom.Models
{
    public class CarViewModel
    {
        public IList<CarModel> CarModel { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to add a controller using the `CarViewModel` class, I get the error message

> CarViewModel: EntityType 'CarViewModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   CarViewModels: EntityType: EntitySet 'CarViewModels' is based on type 'CarViewModel' that has no keys defined.'

I have looked into how to create viewmodels online and have found you do not need to key as this is not a DB Table. Please can someone advise where I have gone wrong with making a viewmodel and why EF thinks this should be a table?

I have also tried to use AutoMapper but the tutorials I found were so old they use features which have now been removed and I have been unable to find a new tutorial which really explains how to implement the mapping and also where I should be writing the 'Maps'.

If anyone could advise on either of the two solutions so I am able to continue learning I would be very grateful as I have been stuck on this problem for weeks. I have also been looking for a small completed project/tutorial which uses AutoMapper so I can read through and understand how AutoMapper works and how/where it should be written but I am unable to find anything.

Thanks,
Danny.

Comment: When you add the controller you are probably selecting `MVC X Controller With Views Using Entity Framework` and then you are selecting the model to be your view model. If you are using a view model, you cannot select that type of controller. Select one of the other types. Then query the database and get the table records. Afterwards, take those and populate your view model from it (either manually or using AutoMapper).

Comment: Put your view models in a separate folder (say `ViewModels`) so they are not associated with EF

Comment: And don't do a DbSet for the viewmodel or try to add it to the database without mapping it back to the entities as Yoshi mentioned.